# Por que aparece una lista de errores que dice lo siguiente PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Phalcon despues de instalar phalcon una Raspberry pi?

Tags: php, phalcon

Realice la compilacion de Phalcon con ayuda de Zephir en un Rasberry pi
Crée un archivo en la carpeta `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/`
El cual nombré phalcon.ini donde agregue la linea extension=phalcon.so
posteriormente cree los links simbolicos en las carpetas:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/50-phalcon.ini  
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/50-phalcon.ini  
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/50-phalcon.ini
```

Que apuntan al archivo creado en la carpeta `mods-available`
reinicio el servidor apache y phpinfo me muestra que phalcon esta instalado

```
Author  Phalcon Team and contributors
Version 3.4.1
Build Date  Nov 7 2018 15:31:40
Powered by Zephir   Version 0.11.2-f1d9feca7b
```

Cuando lanzo el comando `php-v`
obtengo una lista larga de errores que se parecen a los siguientes

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Forms\Element::getAttribute(string $attribute, $defaultValue =
>   NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Forms\ElementInterface::getAttribute($attribute, $defaultValue
>   = NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::readMetaDataIndex(Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface
>   $model, int $index) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaDataInterface::readMetaDataIndex(Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface
>   $model, $index) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::writeMetaDataIndex(Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface
>   $model, int $index, $data) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaDataInterface::writeMetaDataIndex(Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface
>   $model, $index, $data) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error: 
>   Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::readColumnMapIndex(Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface
>   $model, int $index) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaDataInterface::readColumnMapIndex(Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface
>   $model, $index) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Annotations\Adapter::getMethods(string $className): null must
>   be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Annotations\AdapterInterface::getMethods($className) in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Annotations\Adapter::getMethod(string $className, string
>   $methodName) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Annotations\AdapterInterface::getMethod($className,
>   $methodName) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Annotations\Adapter::getProperties(string $className): null
>   must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Annotations\AdapterInterface::getProperties($className) in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Annotations\Adapter::getProperty(string $className, string
>   $propertyName) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Annotations\AdapterInterface::getProperty($className,
>   $propertyName) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Di::offsetExists(string $name): bool must be compatible with
>   ArrayAccess::offsetExists($offset) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Di::offsetGet(string $name): null must
>   be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet($offset) in Unknown on line
>   0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Di::offsetSet(string $name,
>   $definition): bool must be compatible with
>   ArrayAccess::offsetSet($offset, $value) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Di::offsetUnset(string $name): bool
>   must be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset($offset) in Unknown
>   on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset::seek(int $position) must be compatible
>   with SeekableIterator::seek($position) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset::offsetExists(int
>   $index): bool must be compatible with
>   ArrayAccess::offsetExists($offset) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset::offsetGet(int
>   $index) must be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet($offset) in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset::offsetUnset(int $offset) must be
>   compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset($offset) in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Acl\Adapter::getActiveRole():
>   null must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Acl\AdapterInterface::getActiveRole(): string in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Acl\Adapter::getActiveResource(): null must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Acl\AdapterInterface::getActiveResource(): string in Unknown
>   on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Acl\Adapter::getActiveAccess(): null must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Acl\AdapterInterface::getActiveAccess(): string in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory::isAllowed($roleName, $resourceName, string
>   $access, array $parameters = NULL): bool must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Acl\AdapterInterface::isAllowed($roleName, $resourceName,
>   $access, array $parameters = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool
>   $stopBuffer = NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer = NULL) in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Apc::save($keyName = NULL, $content = NULL,
>   $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Apc::delete(string $keyName): bool must be
>   compatible with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::delete($keyName) in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Apc::queryKeys(string $prefix = NULL): null must
>   be compatible with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::queryKeys($prefix =
>   NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool $stopBuffer = NULL) must be
>   compatible with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer =
>   NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\File::save($keyName = NULL, $content = NULL,
>   $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\File::exists($keyName = NULL, int $lifetime =
>   NULL): bool must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::exists($keyName = NULL, $lifetime =
>   NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool $stopBuffer = NULL) must be
>   compatible with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer =
>   NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Libmemcached::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be
>   compatible with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL,
>   $content = NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool $stopBuffer = NULL) must be
>   compatible with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer =
>   NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Memcache::save($keyName = NULL, $content = NULL,
>   $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool
>   $stopBuffer = NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer = NULL) in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Memory::save($keyName = NULL, $content = NULL,
>   $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool
>   $stopBuffer = NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer = NULL) in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Mongo::save($keyName = NULL, $content = NULL,
>   $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool
>   $stopBuffer = NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer = NULL) in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Redis::save($keyName = NULL, $content = NULL,
>   $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Cache\Backend::stop(bool
>   $stopBuffer = NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::stop($stopBuffer = NULL) in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Xcache::save($keyName = NULL, $content = NULL,
>   $lifetime = NULL, bool $stopBuffer = NULL): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Cache\BackendInterface::save($keyName = NULL, $content =
>   NULL, $lifetime = NULL, $stopBuffer = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Crypt::encry``pt(string
>   $text, string $key = NULL): string must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\CryptInterface::encrypt(string $text, $key = NULL): string in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Crypt::decrypt(string $text, $key = NULL): string must be
>   compatible with Phalcon\CryptInterface::decrypt(string $text, string
>   $key = NULL): string in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error: 
>   Declaration of Phalcon\Db\Adapter::limit(string $sqlQuery, int
>   $number): string must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::limit($sqlQuery, $number) in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter::createView(string $viewName, array $definition,
>   $schemaName = NULL): bool must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::createView(string $viewName, array
>   $definition, string $schemaName = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Db\Adapter::dropIndex(string
>   $tableName, string $schemaName, $indexName): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::dropIndex(string $tableName, string
>   $schemaName, string $indexName): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::describeIndexes(string $table, $schema =
>   NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::describeIndexes(string $table, string
>   $schema = NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter::limit(string $sqlQuery, int $number): string must
>   be compatible with Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::limit($sqlQuery,
>   $number) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter::createView(string $viewName, array $definition,
>   $schemaName = NULL): bool must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::createView(string $viewName, array
>   $definition, string $schemaName = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Db\Adapter::dropIndex(string
>   $tableName, string $schemaName, $indexName): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::dropIndex(string $tableName, string
>   $schemaName, string $indexName): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Db\Adapter::describeIndexes(string
>   $table, $schema = NULL) must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::describeIndexes(string $table, string
>   $schema = NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Sqlite::describeIndexes($table, $schema = NULL)
>   should be compatible with Phalcon\Db\Adapter::describeIndexes(string
>   $table, $schema = NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  Declaration
>   of Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Sqlite::describeReferences($table, $schema =
>   NULL) should be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter::describeReferences(string $table, string $schema =
>   NULL) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter::limit(string $sqlQuery, int $number): string must
>   be compatible with Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::limit($sqlQuery,
>   $number) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Db\Adapter::createView(string $viewName, array $definition,
>   $schemaName = NULL): bool must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::createView(string $viewName, array
>   $definition, string $schemaName = NULL): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Fatal error:  Declaration of Phalcon\Db\Adapter::dropIndex(string
>   $tableName, string $schemaName, $indexName): bool must be compatible
>   with Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::dropIndex(string $tableName, string
>   $schemaName, string $indexName): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Declaration of
>   Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness::validate(Phalcon\Validation
>   $validation, $field): bool must be compatible with
>   Phalcon\Validation\Validator::validate(Phalcon\Validation $validation,
>   string $attribute): bool in Unknown on line 0 PHP 7.0.30-0+deb9u1
>   (cli) (built: Jun 14 2018 13:50:25) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend
>   Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.30-0+deb9u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Alguien aue me pueda decir que esta pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de error se había reportado en el repositorio de Phalcon Github a lo cual un miembro del proyecto **[comentó](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/13444#issuecomment-437806413)**:

> Please use Zephir 0.10.x to compile Phalcon 3.4.x

En su caso, Phalcon fue compilado con la versión de Zephir 0.11.2 cuando debió ser con la version 0.10.x

Personalmente utilizo el repositorio oficial de Phalcon para la instalación a menos que tenga una necesidad muy especifica, para esto hago la instalación de la siguiente forma **(Ubuntu/Debian**)

```
$ sudo apt install -y curl gettext gd2 libpcre3-dev json mbstring pdo_* fileinfo openssl
$ sudo curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon
```

La documentación completa la puede encontrar [acá](https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.2/en/installation)